# How to Concat 2 Pandas dataframes with different column numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .xlsx file I am creating two dataframes from and then trying to concat them so that the right columns append to the bottom of the left columns. How do I get the data in the 2nd dataframe to move directly below the 1st dataframe with each dataframe having a different number of columns?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
header = data[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']]
detail = data[['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7']]
combined = pd.concat([header, detail], ignore_index=True)
combined.to_csv('output.csv')
```

**test.xlsx**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc | ddddd | eeeee | fffff | ggggg |

**Actual: output.csv**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | ddddd | eeeee | fffff | ggggg |

**Expected: output.csv**

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 | col_6 | col_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaa | bbbbb | ccccc |  |  |  |  |
| ddddd | eeeee | fffff | ggggg |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
header = data[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']]
detail = data[['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7']]

detail.columns=data.columns[:len(detail.columns)]
header.columns=data.columns[:len(header.columns)]
combined = pd.concat([header, detail])
for i in data.columns:
    if i in combined.columns:
        pass
    else:
        combined[i]=np.nan
```

Comment: axis=1 puts them back the way they were in the original file so both the header and detail records are in one row.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
header = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
detail = ['col_4', 'col_5', 'col_6', 'col_7']
​
func = lambda x: dict(zip(x, range(1, len(x)+1)))
​
out = (
        pd.concat([data.loc[:, header].rename(columns= func(header)),
                   data.loc[:, detail].rename(columns= func(detail))],
                  ignore_index=True, axis=0)
      )
​
out.loc[:, header] = np.NaN
​
out.columns = data.columns
​
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
​
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7
0  aaaaa  bbbbb  ccccc    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  ddddd  eeeee  fffff  ggggg    NaN    NaN    NaN
```